# How to end a while loop and follow the other instructions if the number 0 is entered

Tags: python, python-3.x

My code puts all of he users entered items into a a list
I want it to stop when 0 is entered and follow the other commans such as sorting the list, deleting the highest and lowest values and then finding the average of them
Here is the Code so far:

```
i = 0
sizes = []
while i == 0:
    size = int(input("Enter the weight of your parcel in grams, enter 0 when done: "))
    sizes.append(size)
    if size < 1:
        break
sortedsizes = sorted(sizes)
largest = max(sizes)
smallest = min(sizes)
sizes.remove(largest)
sizes.remove(smallest)
print(sizes)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You do not need `i` and you do not want packages that weight less the 0. You might want to consider using `float` instead of `int` - where I live we measure `kg` for packages or `g` for letters - both will be taken including fractions ( 1.235kg or 5.28g).

If someone inputs `"22kg"` any number conversion will crash - you should guard against it:

```
sizes = []
while True:
    try:
        size = int(input("Enter the weight of your parcel in grams, enter 0 when done: "))
        if size > 0:  
            sizes.append(size)
        elif size == 0:
            break
        else:
            raise ValueError()  # negative weight
    except ValueError:
        print("Only positive numbers or 0 to quit. Do not input text or kg/g/mg.")

sortedsizes = sorted(sizes) # you do nothing with this - why sort at all?
largest = max(sizes)
smallest = min(sizes)
sizes.remove(largest)
sizes.remove(smallest)
print(sizes)  # this prints the unsorted list that got min/max removed...
```

Output:

```
Enter the weight of your parcel in grams, enter 0 when done: 4 
Enter the weight of your parcel in grams, enter 0 when done: 3 
Enter the weight of your parcel in grams, enter 0 when done: 5 
Enter the weight of your parcel in grams, enter 0 when done: 6 
Enter the weight of your parcel in grams, enter 0 when done: -1 
Only positive numbers or 0 to quit. Do not input text or kg/g/mg.
Enter the weight of your parcel in grams, enter 0 when done: DONE 
Only positive numbers or 0 to quit. Do not input text or kg/g/mg. 
Enter the weight of your parcel in grams, enter 0 when done: 2 
Enter the weight of your parcel in grams, enter 0 when done: 0

[4, 3, 5]  # this is the unsorted list that got min/max removed...
```

---

If you want to remove only 1 maximal and 1 minimal value from the sorted list you can simplyfy it:

```
sortedsizes = sorted(sizes)  
maxval = sortedsizes.pop()    # remove last one from sortedsizes  (== max)
minval = sortedsizes.pop(0)   # remove first one from sortedsizes (== min)
print(sortedsizes)            # print the sorted values
```

Doku:

- [pop() doku](https://docs.python.org/3.1/tutorial/datastructures.html#more-on-lists)
- [try: catch: error handling](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/errors.html)

Comment: Your method does not include all of the inputs such as in your example 6 and 2

Comment: @SamardeepKhurana  .. You do understand what removing `largest` and `smallest` from `sizes` does ... ?` `2` and `6` are removed because they are the largest and smallest value...

Answer (score -1):

if you want your code to stop(appending sizes to your list and continue with the commands after the repetitive procedure ) when 0 is entered, you have to do the opposite action.

```
while True:
    size = int(input("Enter the weight of your parcel in grams, enter 0 when done: "))
    sizes.append(size)
    if size < 1:
        break
```

While the statement is false, the code continues from the  `sortedsizes = sorted(sizes)` command.

Comment: thanks but it comes up with this error: line 9, in <module>
    largest = max(sizes)
ValueError: max() arg is an empty sequence
>>>

Comment: Your answer will append zero and then exit

Comment: So to avoid that if statement should come first

Comment: @DennisPeterson  no need to - due to `i = 0` the `while` will never be executed anyhow.

Comment: oh yeah I had requested permission to edit the answer but yeah,, it won't be executed, you are right